# Create new type in symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

How can I create FormType in Symfony2 for converting an entity to a string and back?

I've done all that is saying in [here](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) but there is an error:

```
Expected argument of type "string", "<Vendor>\<Bundle>\Entity\User" given
```

How can I create a form where a text field will be converted to an user object?

Comment: Please, can you provide more samples of your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `User` has an `username` field i would do a transform like the following. **Please** pay attention that `transform` is for `User` to `string` transform, while `reverseTransform` is the opposite.

Add the transformer to your form field:

```php
$builder
    ->add('user', 'text')
    ->addViewTransformer($transformer)
```

Relevant code (like example you've cited):

```php
/**
 * Transforms an User to a string.
 *
 * @param  User|null $user
 * @return string
 */
public function transform($user)
{
    return $user ? $user->getUsername() : '';
}

/**
 * Transforms a string to an User.
 *
 * @param  string $username
 * @return User|null
 */
public function reverseTransform($username)
{
    if(empty($username)) return null;

    $user = $this->om
        ->getRepository('AcmeHelloBundle:User')
        ->findOneBy(array('username' => $username))
    ;

    return $user; // Can be null
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I did exactly the same - only I've also created a field type where I use this transformer. My field type is inherited from text field type and there is an error, that it expecting a string but an object is given(my user object)

Answer (score 0):

You can extract this form type here and use that. https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/1951 it does what you are asking.